# Windows Form application on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-code

I am currently studying Visual Basic .Net but I'm currently using Linux Mint 18 Mate and the only Visual Studio that's available is Visual Studio Code. I was wondering if it's able to create Windows Form Application?

Edit: I just want to update this past as technology has progressed and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux only time will make this question obsolete as Microsoft is releasing some of it technologies to linux

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Windows Forms is exclusive to the [Desktop] Windows platform. You can certainly not use VSCode for that, not even in Windows, as VSCode doesn't include form designer tools like the regular Visual Studio IDE. So even in case you could compile, there are still lacking all the facilities needed for designing.

You can rather try with MonoDevelop for Linux (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop)

**Edit:**

A year later and it looks like support is coming. My guess is it won't be as nice as running on windows but it will look better than a Java app: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms

Comment: Alternatively, I suggest to use Electron for building cross-platform desktop applications with VSCode. This project is very helpful: https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET

Comment: WinForms is made open source as part of .NET Core 3, but it is Windows-only (same applies for WPF)

Comment: Another alternative to the bloated Electron is [Sciter](https://sciter.com/), the runtime is about 8MB.

Answer (score 40):

There is an even easier way. From the terminal type this:

```
dotnet new winforms
```

Comment: This is the answer and should be marked as such.

Comment: It is not the answer. The user asked about using forms on Linux Mint 18 which is not possible.
This is why I specified for windows in my answer. And you will find this does not work on windows if you do not have the latest dotnet sdk installed.
I also should point out that it is good for people to understand what is happening in each of the files created. Which is why I provided a detailed explanation instead of spoon-feeding a solution. That being said, for windows, this is a the fastest way of so doing, and thus +1.

Comment: `The template "Windows Forms App" was created successfully.` what more could I ask for? :-)

Comment: I needed to select the `C#` option for debugging, not the `.NET+…`

Answer (score 20):

For those who come here looking for an answer to the question, but for Windows...
Building forms in VSCode is easy. Some would argue easier than in Visual Studio.

1. Download and install the latest [dotnet sdk](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks)
2. Open a new folder in VScode.
3. From the terminal type "dotnet new Console"
4. This will have created some files. When prompted to add necessary files, select yes.
5. From folder view, Select your .csproj file and replace its contents with the following:

   ```
     <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
       <PropertyGroup>
          <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
          <TargetFramework>net4.7.2</TargetFramework>
          <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
          <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
       </PropertyGroup>
     </Project>
   ```

Now, Create a new file and Name it Form1.cs. Populate it as Follows:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    public void FormLayout()
    {
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 500);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    }
}
```

Lastly, Replace the contents of your Program.cs with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Program
{
    public static Form1 form = new Form1();
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        form.FormLayout();;
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

7. Save. Now, in the terminal type "dotnet run" and press enter. A form will appear.

This should give you the foundational understanding necessary to build any windows forms project in vscode. You can also build custom controls but that is another beast entirely.

I have created a sample project for those interested [Example Here](https://github.com/Triangle4/WinFormsVSCode)

Comment: Not at all. But everyone has preferences and they are no less valid than any preference that you may have. I personally use winforms in vscode.
It is lightweight and powerful and I can move fast through it, with very few background operations counteracting certain programming preferences that I maintain. 

Additionally the asked question is  regarding winforms in vscode. So if you have an objection, it clearly shows you came here looking for a disagreement, rather than to contribute to the growth and overall health of the community.

If you have nothing nice to say, don't say anything :)

Comment: designing the UI with no visual design view is difficult i think...

Answer (score 3):

According to the link below, VS Code does not support Desktop .NET Framework. Because VS Code is design to be Cross-Platform. Meaning that you can't work with "windows forms".

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp

*Side-Note:*
I was wondering the same question while coding C# in Windows when I received "include System.Windows.Forms" was missing assembly references.

Answer (score 0):

However if you want to develop Windows Based Applications using C#, you can use MonoDevelop Application in Linux for sure..

Answer (score 0):

I have built an Excel VBA application that lets you use the Excel IDE UserForm designer to layout your form and a macro that generates tkinter Python code that renders the form.  The largest challenge is that for some widgets, tkinter uses font size for height/width where Excel uses Points.
kenshep@cox.net

Comment: windows forms are rendered by python using tkinter??

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).